# Is 'Data Driven Subscriptions' feature available in Developer Edition?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

We have installed 2012 Developer Edition.
Is `Data Driven Subscriptions` feature available in Developer Edition like Enterprise Edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `Data Driven Subscription` is available in developer edition.

Per Microsoft:

> SQL Server 2012 Developer edition lets developers build any kind of
>   application on top of SQL Server. It includes all the functionality of
>   Enterprise edition, but is licensed for use as a development and test
>   system, not as a production server. SQL Server Developer is an ideal
>   choice for people who build and test applications.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144275(v=sql.110).aspx

To find out what version/edition of Sql Server you are running. Run this:

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```